# Remote Control Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote, bluetooth, radio

Is there any other way to remotely control the raspberry pi? I built a 4 wheeled robot that is automated by ultrasonic sensors, yet today I have to decided it to make it remote controlled, what are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of remote control, you've got a few options.
You could SSH into the Pi and control it via the command line. You could install VNC on the Pi and then use a client on another computer to connect to it that way.
Alternatively, you could use a bluetooth dongle and pair up a Wii remote, PS3 controller or anything else that uses the bluetooth protocol. There are a variety of tutorials available online for all of them, so let us know if any of those take your fancy :-)

Comment: I guess the PS3 controller would sound perfect since I already have it in my arsenal, problem is what's the range limit for bluetooth devices?

Comment: Oh there _is_ a limit, I'm sure. But I think you'll find that you'll want to keep it within visual range anyway so you should find it's okay. Take a look at the Pi Borg website for some info on using the PS3 controller. https://www.piborg.org/doodleborg/ps3-source